# Sitecore.ListManagement.ListManagerGetContacts Recipient list is always null EXM

Tags: experience-analytics, exm

I am trying to create an EXM campaign. Somehow, I can send a test e-mail but it always fail, when I try to send it to a list of recipients.

**What I did**:
1- Create a new list by uploading a CSV file (successful but list is only available in English version)
2- Create my email campaign
3- Assign the list to my email campaign.

**Expected result**: 
No error message should be shown and EXM is able to retrieve and process the list

**Actual result**:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: list]   
  Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +63
  Sitecore.ListManagement.ListManager`2.GetContacts(TContactList list) +39
  Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.RecipientManager.GetMessageRecipients() +119
  Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.RecipientManager.GetTargetRecipientCount() +14
  Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.MessageStateInfo.get_NumSubscribers() +49
  Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.MessageInfo.get_To() +77
  Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.sitecore_modules.Shell.EmailCampaign.UI.Editors.MessagePreviewPage.FillMessageHeader(MessageInfo info) +266
  Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.sitecore_modules.Shell.EmailCampaign.UI.Editors.MessagePreviewPage.FillPreviewSection() +254
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +251   
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4088
```

**Additional information**:
I am using this patch [Sitecore.Support.162905-8.2.3.0.zip](https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/1okdk19c769x1874yauoltmtitq51qur)

**Question**:
I am pretty sure that either I am doing something wrong or forgot to configure something, can somebody help?

Comment: Which version of EXM and Sitecore you have installed?

Answer (score 2):

Edit to my below answer:

I found [this link](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/577247) in the Sitecore knowledgebase. This might be an answer to the nagging issue.

Please feel free to refer the below answer though:

---

We have been through a similar issue and I actually have a post [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8537/sitecore-list-manager-indexing-issue-recipient-count-is-always-0/8592#8592) that hopefully will help you get a bit further. As far as I have heard, this is a known issue within Sitecore v8.2.

Answer (score 0):

There are some potential solutions in your case:

1) Check if the Global Opt-out List is selected. Navigate to the current *EXM Manager Root* item and check if `Global Opt-out List` is chosen.

2) Could you make sure that you selected an `Exclude lists` for the newly created email campaign as well as the `Include lists`

3) Navigate to the contact list that you uploaded based on the CSV file and make sure that it isn't being indexed and locked. (warnings will be there if it is)